# deleting tables from postgresql without raising cross-database references are not implemented: using pandas/psycopg2

Tags: sql, pandas, postgresql, schema, psycopg2

I am trying to drop a table from a database.
As long as `name_Table` is a structured as

```
schema.table
```

it all works nicely. However, I do have one table in `public` schema.
When I try to delete it as:

```
public.subname.table
```

I get this answer:

```
cross-database references are not implemented: "public.subname.table"
```

How to drop `public.subname.table`?

```
        print('Connecting to the PostgreSQL database...')
        postgresConnection = psycopg2.connect(
                    host=XXXXXX,
                    port=YYYYYYYYY,
                    database="mydb",
                    user=os.environ['user'],
                    password=os.environ['pwd'])

     
        cursor                = postgresConnection.cursor()
        dropTableStmt   = "drop TABLE %s;"%name_Table;

        # Create a table in PostgreSQL database
        print(dropTableStmt)
        cursor.execute(dropTableStmt)
        postgresConnection.commit()
        cursor.close();
        print('Database cursor closed.')
        postgresConnection.close()
        print('Database connection closed.')
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `public.subname.table`. There is a `public` schema and there can be tables in it, so you can have `public.table`. Also for reasons shown here [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) you don't want to use ` dropTableStmt   = "drop TABLE %s;"%name_Table;`.

Comment: ok. But my table in public have a dot in their name e.g. public.subname.name.how to drop those?  If I just drop  subname.name, I get the error in the original quesiton

Comment: Well that was a bad idea. You now have to quote the name. The best way is `drop TABLE quote_ident(%s)`. Then spend some time here [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) to save you more problems down the road.

Comment: Can you make it an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public.subname.table` runs afoul of [Identifier](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) rules in that '.' is not a valid character. <s>The way around that is to double quote the identifier e.g. "public.subname.table" or use the function [quote_ident](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) like `quote_ident(public.subname.table)`. In your case `drop TABLE quote_ident(%s)`.</s>

**UPDATE**

Previous solution was not. I did not test it and just assumed. A tested solution:

```
--In psql
create table "public.subname.table"(id int);

select * from "public.subname.table";
 id 
----
(0 rows)

--In Python
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql 

con = psycopg2.connect(dbname="test", host='localhost', user='postgres') 

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(sql.SQL("DROP table {table}").format(table=sql.Identifier("public.subname.table")))
con.commit()

--psql
select * from "public.subname.table";
ERROR:  relation "public.subname.table" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from "public.subname.table";
```

This makes use of the `psycopg2` [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) module to properly and safely quote the table name in a query string.

Comment: Unfortunately I get syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: drop TABLE quote_ident (public.subname.table); when using drop TABLE quote_ident(%s)

Comment: See my UPDATE with an answer that works.

Answer (score 1):

`DROP TABLE public."subname.table"` does what you want.

`sql.Identifier("public", "subname.table")` is what you want as psycopg2 identifier.